# Modifying a List of Objects through a List of Wrappers

Tags: c#, wpf, list

My goal here is to retrieve a List from a class instance and then modify the objects within that list, however I do not know how the objects will be affected and need some valuable knowledge.

Let's say we have two cases:

1. Create a new List which gets the list from the class instance:

   ```
   List<SomeType> ItemsList {get { return classInstance.ItemsList;} set {...
   ```
2. Create a new List of wrappers, each item in the list contains the original object with some additional properties:

   ```
   List<SomeType> itemsList = classInstance.ItemsList;
   List<Wrapper> wrapperList = itemsList.Select(x => new Wrapper {Item = x, IsSelected = ...
   ```

My question is, if I were to modify the objects in `ItemsList` and `wrapperList`, would the changes be reflected in the `classInstance`?

I will be using multiple `ObservableCollections` in multiple `DataGrids`, I have used `Lists` in this example simplify the situation but I'm sure the result would be the same.

**Edit:**

I realize the Title does not describe my problem well, I encourage anyone to help me improve it.

Comment: "would the changes be reflected in the classInstance" Did you try it out?

Comment: You should add some examples of what you want to modify exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is, if I were to modify the objects in `ItemsList` and `wrapperList`, would the changes be reflected in the `classInstance`?

Yes, unless you create a copy `SomeType` and add the copy to the new collection.

The following creates a new `Wrapper` objects for each `SomeType` object...

```
List<Wrapper> wrapperList = itemsList.Select(x => new Wrapper {Item = x } );
```

...but each `Wrapper` object still has a reference (though the `Item` property) to the same `SomeType` object that's in `classInstance.ItemsList`.

Answer (score 0):

1. When the properties of SomeType (mutable reference type) instances are changed via Wrapper then the objects in the original list change, because they are the same objects.
2. When the list holding Wrapper objects changes (you move, add or remove objects) the the original list is not affected.
3. When original list is changed (you move, add or remove objects) the list containing Wrappers is not affected.

To synchronise the collections, you should use ObservableCollection for original list and implement collection (probably also ObservableCollection-derived) for Wrappers that auto-updates itself when source collection changes.